# Serious problem Firebase read rule for blocked user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am facing with a serious problem with Firebase security rule. I want to set `read` to false to blocked user on search. Here is my database structure.

```
users:{
      uid1:{
           name:"Joe",
           created:1226287
          },
      uid2:{
          name:"John",
          created:1273725
          },
      uid3:{...},
      uid4:{...},
      ...
   },

 blocked:{
       uid1:{
            uid2: true,
            uid4: true
       }
   }
```

Consider above structure, assume that `user2` search a user under `users` node by name typing "Joe" and click enter.  I set my firebase rule like this.

```
 users:{
     $uid:{
         ".read":"!root.child('blocked').child($uid).hasChild(auth.uid)"
         }
     }
```

This rule works fine if `user2`  query `user/user1` path. But when `user2` searched, how can I prevent him from getting blocked user data.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way of getting users lists that haven't blocked that particular user. But if the user is doing a search based on the user name or some other user-based criteria then the best tool is Firebase Functions.

Step to implement the function (Considering search is based on name) ( From the client-side you invoke firebase functions and pass the search name ):

1. get all the user details which are having the same name.
2. get all the user (or the user who has the same name) who has blocked the requesting user.
3. pop all the user who blocked the requested user.
4. send back the user list to the requested user.

Why Firebase Function is the optimal choice in the situation? Because the functions are executed in a secured environment and can bypass the security rules.

[Read more about the functions here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions)

Comment: Is this the best and only way to implement search feature? (In order to use cloud function, I have to upgrade my account to **Pay-as-you-go** plan and my country, Myanmar, is not in the list in creating billing account. :'(  )

Comment: From my perspective, I don't see any other way of doing it. Keeping the logic of getting unblocked users on the client-side can be risky (and FYI I won't suggest you do it). To overcome this you can use firebase functions that are executed in a safe environment, away from the client-side.

Comment: And about creating a billing account in Myanmar, go through some post regarding it. Someone might have got that problem and might have offered some solution for it.

Comment: I found no solution about creating billing account from Myanmar. I contacted to the help organization and they replied to wait. :'(